# How to add parameter in beforeEach

Tags: vue-router

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (auth) {
    next()
  } else {
    next('/')
  }
})
```

Using `vue-router` `beforeEach` controls `auth`, if success `true` go `next` otherwise redirect to `'/'`. it's working, but I wish redirect to home `'/'` and pop up the login dialog.

So I change to this:

```
next({path: '/', params: { showLogin: true }})
```

when I set `auth` to false, in my `home.vue`, `console.log(this.$route.params.showLogin)` gives `undefined`